# Bounce handling with amazon-ses not working

Tags: civimail, amazon-ses

I am trying to get the extension [amazon-ses](https://github.com/mecachisenros/civicrm-ses) working. I have created an AWS account, signed up for SES mail, and verified my domain. DKIM and SPF are working and verified.  I signed up for SNS, created a topic and subscribed to it using the webhook address defined by the extension. Civimail is configured to send to amazon by SMTP. When I sent a civimail to the list, it was delivered, so the SMTP setup is correct.

However I received a warning note from Amazon saying that our bounce rate is too high. Ok, but in civimail it says there were zero bounces from that mail, so clearly the bounces are not coming back through the extension. How do I debug this setup?

I am aware that the extension is marked alpha code, but I would like to get it going if possible.  Any pointers would be appreciated.